# Jenkinsfile - File not found when shell script is referred from another file

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh

I am trying to execute the shell script from outside the jenkinsfile but doesn't seem to work.

```
#!/bin/bash

basePath=$1
file=$2

path=$basePath/$file
res=$("test -f $path && echo '1' || echo '0' ")

if [ $res == '1' ]
 then
...
```

The jenkinsfile is

```
        def basePath = xxx
        ...  
        stage('Prepare') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh "chmod +x ./scripts/unzip.sh"
                    sh "./scripts/unzip.sh ${basePath} ${params.file}"
                }
            }
        }
```

I am getting an error at line `res=$("test -f $path && echo '1' || echo '0' ")` where it says `No such file or directory`. But the path is valid and it works when I run the command within the jenkinsfile.
Not sure why it is giving error when I move the code to another file.

Answer (score 1):

`"anything inside double quotes"` is a single argument, so there is no executable named literally `"test -f $path && echo '1' || echo '0' "` on your system. Instead, there is `test` and `echo`. Do:

```
res=$(test -f "$path" && echo 1 || echo 0)
```

But really, why res? Just:

```
if test -f "$path"; then
```

Even with res, then:

```
test -f "$path"
res=$?
if ((res == 0)); then
```

Check your scripts with shellcheck .

Answer (score 1):

When you do a

```
 x=$("foo bar baz")
```

the quotes have the effect, that the whole quoted script (`foo bar baz`) is taken as the name of an executable which is searched in the PATH.

You would receive the same error message, if you would do just a

```
"test -f $path && echo '1' || echo '0' "
```

Quote only that part which makes sense to be quoted; in your case

```
res=$(test -f "$path" && echo 1 || echo 0)
```